# python insert into mysql table errors

Tags: python

to write python program to insert data in mysql table fb_web_active_group_members_user_hClustering_six

```
if cur.execute(is_exist_table_sql) == 0:
    create_sql  = '''CREATE TABLE fb_web_active_group_members_user_hClustering_six (id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,userID bigint,GroupName varchar(128),
                Friends int,NoProfilePhotos int,UploadPhotoSum int,NoPosts int,UploadVideoSum int,postCluster0 int,postCluster1 int,postCluster2 int,postCluster3 int,postCluster4 int,
                normal_Friends float,normal_NoProfilePhotos float,normal_UploadPhotoSum float,normal_NoPosts float,normal_UploadVideoSum float,normal_postCluster0 float,
                normal_postCluster1 float,normal_postCluster2 float,normal_postCluster3 float,normal_postCluster4 float,postCluster0_ratio float,postCluster1_ratio float,
                postCluster2_ratio float,postCluster3_ratio float,postCluster4_ratio float, cluster_label int)'''
    cur.execute(create_sql)

for item in user_level_cluster_list:
    insert_sql = '''INSERT INTO fb_web_active_group_members_user_hClustering_six (userID,GroupName,
                Friends,NoProfilePhotos,UploadPhotoSum,NoPosts,UploadVideoSum,postCluster0,postCluster1,postCluster2,postCluster3,postCluster4,
                normal_Friends,normal_NoProfilePhotos,normal_UploadPhotoSum,normal_NoPosts,normal_UploadVideoSum,normal_postCluster0,
                normal_postCluster1,normal_postCluster2,normal_postCluster3,normal_postCluster4,postCluster0_ratio,postCluster1_ratio,
                postCluster2_ratio,postCluster3_ratio,postCluster4_ratio, cluster_label) VALUES
                ({0},"{1}",{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16}，{17}，{18}，{19}，{20}，{21}，{22}，{23}，{24},{25},{26},{27})'''.format(item["UserID"],
                                                                               item["GroupName"],item["Friends"],item["NoProfilePhotos"],item["UploadPhotoSum"],
                                                                               item["NoPosts"], item["UploadVideoSum"],item["postCluster0"],item["postCluster1"],item["postCluster2"],item["postCluster3"],
                                                                               item["postCluster4"],"%.5f"% item["normal_Friends"],"%.5f"%item["normal_NoProfilePhotos"],"%.5f"%item["normal_UploadPhotoSum"],"%.5f"%item["normal_NoPosts"],
                                                                                "%.5f" %item["normal_UploadVideoSum"],"%.5f"%item["normal_postCluster0"],"%.5f"%item["normal_postCluster1"],"%.5f"%item["normal_postCluster2"],
                                                                                "%.5f" %item["normal_postCluster3"],"%.5f"%item["normal_postCluster4"],"%.5f"%item["postCluster0_ratio"],"%.5f"%item["postCluster1_ratio"],
                                                                                "%.5f" %item["postCluster2_ratio"],"%.5f"%item["postCluster3_ratio"],"%.5f"%item["postCluster4_ratio"],item["cluster_label"])


    print(insert_sql)
    cur.execute(insert_sql)
```

but it errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    INSERT INTO fb_web_active_group_members_user_hClustering_six (userID,GroupName,Friends,NoProfilePhotos,UploadPhotoSum,NoPosts,UploadVideoSum,postCluster0,postCluster1,postCluster2,postCluster3,postCluster4,normal_Friends,normal_NoProfilePhotos,normal_UploadPhotoSum,normal_NoPosts,normal_UploadVideoSum,normal_postCluster0,normal_postCluster1,normal_postCluster2,normal_postCluster3,normal_postCluster4,postCluster0_ratio,postCluster1_ratio,postCluster2_ratio,postCluster3_ratio,postCluster4_ratio, cluster_label) VALUES (1,"Jazzmasters&Jaguars",964,195,5,339,0,119,14,73,20,36,0.19280,0.17016,0.00028,0.37184,0.00000，0.27483，0.09589，0.20055，0.18868，0.15000，0.45420，0.05344，0.27863,0.07634,0.13740,4.00000)


pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '，0.27483，0.09589，0.20055，0.18868，0.15000，0.45420，0.05344，0.27863' at line 6")
```

could you please tell me the reason and how to resolve it

Comment: Midway the query your commas are starting to get wierd: `{14},{15},{16}，{17}，{18}`

Answer (score 0):

Please, please use the standard syntax presented in [MySQL python docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html).

I.e. the format of your query should be:

```
 query = ("INSERT INTO table"
           "(col1, col2, col3, col4)"
           "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")
 data = (value1, value2, value3, value4)
 cursor.execute(query, data)
```

Don't use the python `{}`-formats. Your current implementation (if it happened to work, which it luckily does not, probably due to those weird commas) would be vulnerable to SQL-injections.